# WordPress как сделать отправку сообщений без перезагрузки

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, email

Как сделать отправку формы без перезагрузки страницы на wordpress?

---

Вот форма (html)

```
<form class="form" method="post">
   <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя..." required>
   <input id="phone" class="input" type="text" name="phone" required>
   <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш Email (по желанию)">
   <button name="submitted" class="send">Отправить заявку</button>
</form>
```

---

Вот отправка (php)

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
   $title = "Форма с сайта с гитарами";
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
   $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
   $phone = htmlspecialchars($phone);
   $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
   $name = urldecode($name);
   $phone = urldecode($phone);
   $email = urldecode($email);
   mail("mymail@mail.ru", $title, "Имя: ".$name."\r\nТелефон:".$phone."\r\nПочта: ".$email);
 }
?>
```

---

html и php все в одном файле (index.php)

Обычно, когда я делаю отправку без перезагрузки, я использую атрибут action для формы. Но в WorPress он не может открыть просто так файл, т.е. он не находит файл mail.php.

---

Вот такой код я обычно использую для отправки сообщений без перезагрузки.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = jQuery(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('fail');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return true;
  });
});
```

Но тут такое не прокатит, потому что отправка находится в одном файле с самой формой. И вот самое главное, **как мне сделать отправку формы без перезагрузки правильно?**

P.s. Еще меня смущает, что после отправки формы, появляется страница 404.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, где у вас action в самой форме? А во-вторых, в WordPress лучше делать всё по стандартам самого WordPress. Инструкция по ajax в WP на русском: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html. В-третьих, mail() плохая функция, в WP есть существенно улучшенная wp_mail(), разработанная как раз для решения многих проблем на shared-хостингах. Но для её работы нужно подключенное ядро WP, см. инструкцию выше.

Comment: `Но в worpress он не может открыть просто так файл, т.е. он не находит файл mail.php` просто надо правильно указать к нему путь.

Comment: А можно по подробнее? Вот как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Надо добавить echo get_template_directory_uri() ?

Comment: Да у меня получилось это сделать)

Comment: @olishevskyalex ответы - в ответы)